# net.minecraft.util.ReportedException: Ticking entity

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm new to java and I'm following a tutorial to create a mod for using MCP for Minecraft 1.12.2 (the tutorial was for  MC 1.8, so I've had to change a few things) LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n33Ig58s9YQ. I've made an event system with enums for finding the direction of an event and if it is Pre or Post tick.

(The Tick() method is from the minecraft code that runs about 20 times a second)

So, The code from 11 - 13 of tick(), creates an instance of the EventUpdate class (EventUpdate is a type of the Event class below)
It sets the instance to EventType.PRE and runs the onEvent() method on it, which is also below.

this is the error I get:

```
[16:37:57] [Client thread/FATAL]: Reported exception thrown!
net.minecraft.util.ReportedException: Ticking entity

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at Client.ClientMain.onEvent(ClientMain.java:26)
    at net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityPlayerSP.tick(EntityPlayerSP.java:233)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72866_a(World.java:1882)
    at net.minecraft.world.World.func_72870_g(World.java:1849)

-- Entity being ticked --

Details:
    Entity Type: null (net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityPlayerSP)
    Entity ID: 211
    Entity Name: Player952
    Entity's Exact location: 560.74, 72.00, 310.85
    Entity's Block location: World: (560,72,310), Chunk: (at 0,4,6 in 35,19; contains blocks 560,0,304 to 575,255,319), Region: (1,0; contains chunks 32,0 to 63,31, blocks 512,0,0 to 1023,255,511)
    Entity's Momentum: 0.00, -0.08, 0.00
    Entity's Passengers: []
    Entity's Vehicle: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

This is the MC tick() method:

```
    /**
     * Called to update the entity's position/logic.
     */
    public void tick()
    {
        
        if (this.world.isBlockLoaded(new BlockPos(this.posX, 0.0D, this.posZ)))
        {
            super.tick();
            
            EventUpdate e = new EventUpdate();
            e.setType(EventType.PRE);
            ClientMain.onEvent(e);

            if (this.isPassenger())
            {
                this.connection.sendPacket(new CPacketPlayer.Rotation(this.rotationYaw, this.rotationPitch, this.onGround));
                this.connection.sendPacket(new CPacketInput(this.moveStrafing, this.moveForward, this.movementInput.jump, this.movementInput.field_78899_d));
                Entity entity = this.getLowestRidingEntity();

                if (entity != this && entity.canPassengerSteer())
                {
                    this.connection.sendPacket(new CPacketVehicleMove(entity));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
                this.onUpdateWalkingPlayer();
                
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally, this is the main script:

```
package Client;

import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import Client.events.Event;
import Client.modules.Module;
import Client.modules.movement.Fly;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class ClientMain {
    
    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<Module> modules = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Module>();
    
    public static String ClientName = "Client", Version = "0.1";
    
    public static void StartUp() {
        Display.setTitle(ClientName + " v" + Version);
        
        modules.add(new Fly());
    }
    
    public static void onEvent(Event e) {
        for(Module m : modules) {
            if (!m.toggled)
                continue;
            
            m.onEvent(e);
        }
    }
    
    public static void keyPress(int key) {
        for(Module m : modules) {
            if(m.getKey() == key) {
                m.toggle();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you can help me, I've been stuck on this for a while now, Thx! :)
and I don't know if anymore code is needed please ask me though.

Comment: It's a bit of a relief to see such a well-formulated question in the Minecraft tag. Do you have a longer error message? Could you post the complete one?

Comment: Just to clarify, is the `tick()` method pulled directly from Minecraft's code, or did you make it?

Comment: I would suggest looking at a more recent tutorial, there's no need to create your own event system, it's built directly into Forge via [Events](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events/intro/).